# Ionic Build Android Faild on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: android, apache, cordova, ant, ionic-framework

Ionic/Corodva works file on my Mac OS X 10.10 with iOS Platform, but it faild to build android, how ever I can add the platform android successfully. android api 19 installed

my .bash_profile:

> export ANT_HOME=/Users/ayman/ant
>
> export
>   PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/Users/ayman/adt/sdk/platform-tools:$ANT_HOME/bin:/Users/ayman/adt/sdk/tools;

and this is the error:

> BUILD FAILED /Users/ayman/adt/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:892: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/ayman/adt/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:894: The following error
>   occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/ayman/adt/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:906: The following error
>   occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/ayman/adt/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:283: Execute failed:
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/Users/ayman/adt/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/dx" (in directory
>   "/Users/ayman/desktop/androidtest/platforms/android"): error=13,
>   Permission denied     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:628)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:669)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:495)
>     at com.android.ant.DexExecTask.runDx(DexExecTask.java:272)  at
>   com.android.ant.DexExecTask.runDx(DexExecTask.java:235)   at
>   com.android.ant.DexExecTask.preDexLibraries(DexExecTask.java:154)     at
>   com.android.ant.DexExecTask.execute(DexExecTask.java:210)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>     at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>     at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>     at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109) Caused
>   by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied  at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:185)    at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)  ... 93 more
>
> Total time: 5 seconds Error code 1 for command: ant with args:
>   debug,-f,/Users/ayman/desktop/androidtest/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
>   Error:
>   /Users/ayman/desktop/androidtest/platforms/android/cordova/build:
>   Command failed with exit code 2
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try with

`export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/your/path/to/ANDROIDSDK`

before platform add

Comment: didn't work for me:

export ANT_HOME=/Users/ayman/ant
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/ayman/adt/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANT_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/tools;

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot run program "/Users/ayman/adt/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/dx" (in directory "/Users/ayman/desktop/androidtest/platforms/android"): error=13, Permission denied at

Sounds like you have a permission issue.  I'd change the permissions to 755 or 77.

Regards,

Comment: I tried: chmod 777 for this folder /Users/ayman/desktop/androidtest/platforms/android, but still same,, also I tried: sudo cordova build android ,, but not work also

Comment: You have a permission denied error so somewhere your permissions are not correct.  Doing a chmod may not be enough.  You may need to recursively chmod the path.  The error is complaining about the path so it is best to start there.

Answer (score 0):

I solved The problem by just installing more versions of SDK Build tools from 21 to 18.0.1

Comment: First I had 21 and 19 only, but yesterday I installed from 18.0.1 to 21.1, but I think you are right, may be its 19.1 and it works fine now